# Big-O simplification

Tags: big-o

I'm trying to get a better understanding of big-o simplification. The question posed was to simplify the following:

> 2log(n) + 12sin(n).

I posed that 2log(n) would be simplified to lg(n) and 12sin(n) would be simplified to sin(n).

> lg(n) + sin(n)

Is there any further simplification required?

Comment: sinus is periodic, so in Big-O it counts as constant.

Comment: Ah I see, that makes sense. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Máté Juhász beat me to the answer, you can simplify this to:

```
O(log (N))
```

Other than being periodic, the maximum value of `sin(n)` is `1` so you can treat it as a constant.

I have also ignored the multiplication by 2 as the big-O notation only describes the long-term growth rate of functions, rather than their absolute magnitudes. Multiplying a function by a constant, only influences its growth rate by a constant amount, so linear functions still grow linearly and logarithmic functions still grow logarithmically.